# Происхождение русского мата

Tags: этимология, обсценная-лексика

Правда ли, что матерные ругательства пришли в русский язык от татаро-монгольских завоевателей?

Answer (score 1):

Как человек владеющий несколькими тюркскими языками подтверждаю, что в тюркских языках мат совершенно не такой.

В тюркских языках мат есть, но не такой виртуозный как в русском, и несет совершенно другую и фонетическую и смысловую нагрузку.

Comment: А какую? Особенно смысловую. У нас ругательство - способ сбросить нервное напряжение (кроме, конечно, очевидной функции оскорбления)

Comment: В тюркских языках мат - это в общем то средство оскорбления и унижения. Конечно, есть влияние русского когда мат используется как средство снятия нервного напряжения. Но это касается "цензурной" части брани, нецензурная безусловное табу и считается тяжким оскорблением.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно же к тюркизмам русский мат не имеет никакого отношения.
Но и к языческим идолам - тем более.
Все слова имеют вполне бытовое происхождение, большинство из них вовсе не были изначально табуированы. В Интернете можно найти вполне вменяемые трактовки всех "матерных" слов , здесь приводить их, видимо, "не формат". 
Некоторые расхождения только по поводу трехбуквенного короля всего мата, Фасмер видит в нем родство с хвоей (иголкой), другие источники утверждают образование от латинского местоимения "это", в родительном падеже звучащем созвучно [huik]. Вообще это слово сравнительно недавнее, заменившее историческое "уд" (родственное "удочка").
Остальные слова - от общеславянских корней.

Answer (score -1):

Мат - порождение низших слоёв, где моральных ограничений было минимум (если они были вообще!). Мат употребляли в речи только мужчины. Значит, изначально он возник на основе жестоких междуусобиц: наряду с рычанием, "Ур-ра-а-а!!" и использованием некоторых междометий. Военная лексика закрепилась в бытовой жизни, когда интересы враждующих были слишком антагонистичны. Женщины были очень задавлены, поэтому оскорбление по половому признаку весьма ценилось. Почему именно русский мат самый заковыристый, объяснить трудно. 
Но уж, конечно, это не следствие "избранности народа".